# HTML/CSS not resizing my page correctly

Tags: css, web, html, responsive

So I have my website here: http://easenhall.org.uk/index.html

If you were to reduce the width of the browser window it changes from desktop view to tablet view, then if you keep going it will change to mobile view.

It works on desktop browsers but if you were to look at the website through a mobile it will always display the web page in tablet mode. I cant figure out why.

If you inspect the desktop webpage and press the toggle device toolbar button and try to resize the page to a mobile view, you get a similar effect, it stays in tablet view.

I have checked the console and there are no errors displayed there, I cant find anything wrong with it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You forgot to include viewport meta tag in your header: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add this to your `<header>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

Comment: THANKS :) I have been having trouble with this for ages :) Im assuming I need to add this to every page?

Comment: According to [this](http://a11yproject.com/posts/never-use-maximum-scale/) you should usually not set maximum-scale.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. I copied it from my latest project where it was necessary. I wouldn't say never use it, just be careful. There's a little bit more info about all the possible attributes: http://blog.javierusobiaga.com/stop-using-the-viewport-tag-until-you-know-ho

Comment: @CameronWard yes, it has to be on every page :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this meta tag after the title tag, otherwise responsive does not work

```
<title>This is title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

Answer (score 1):

By way of background, when Apple introduced the iPhone some time back, they anticipated the problem that nobody at the time was writing pages designed for the small screen. This included the relatively new Media Queries, which was at the time still not widely supported.

They made the decision to *scale* the whole screen from a larger version to the small screen. It wasn’t easy to read, but at least you could see see where everything was, and you could always zoom into the interesting part.

The scaling was achieved by creating a *viewport*, an off-screen virtual screen, set to a width of 960px. The page would be rendered there, and scaled to the smaller physical screen.

It also meant that CSS media queries would get a reported width of 960px, and thus would not trigger alternative styles.

Apple also introduced a non-standard `meta` property called `viewport`, which gave the developer some control over the properties of the viewport.

The most common use of the `viewport` property is set the viewport size to the same as the physical screen. The viewort would then report a screen size which is more correct, and CSS Media Queries can do the rest. Effectively, the `viewport` is commonly used to undo the scaling effect.

Desktop browsers never had this issue to begin with, so the viewport is really just the browser window. That is why the desktop always tests as expected, because what you see is really what you get.

Answer (score 0):

This is what vuejs (and probably other frameworks) is doing "under the hood":

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />`

Setting exactly this tag in the header will lead to your desired result.